# Command button in Salesforce is not working on first click

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

I have written one logic in that when we select an object and its related fields on VF page and click on a Add Mapping Button,it will redirect to an other page where selected object and its fields being added.
Issue is that when I click for the first time on the Add mapping button,controller method is not calling up(where I have written my logic).On second click it is working fine.Help will be appreciated.Thanks
I have put system.debug,so on first click it will enter in for loop,but not inside the (w.ischecked) if condition.
my **Vf page** logic for button:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-no-flex slds-grid slds-align-top">
                <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Add Mappings" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" action="{!doSave}"/>
                    <!--<apex:commandLink action="{!doSave}" value="add" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" />-->
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" action="{!doCancel}"/>
                    <!--<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Save Mappings</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Cancel</button> -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

**controller save method**:
 I am pasting the whole code for better understanding:

```
global with sharing class JNMappings{  public string fieName{get;set;}
    public list<mappingWrap> fieldLst{get;set;}
    public list<mappingWrap> fieldLstToShow{get;set;}
    public string selectedValue{get;set;}
    public string objLabel{get;set;}
    transient map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap;
    transient map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap;
    public List<SelectOption> objvalues{get;set;}
    public Mapping__c mapObj{get;set;}
    public string objName{get;set;}
    public boolean fieldFlag{get;set;}
    //Constructor
    public JNMappings(){
        fieldLstToShow = new list<mappingWrap>();
        fieldLst = new list<mappingWrap>();
        JNGenericUtilClass gen = new JNGenericUtilClass();
        dispFlag = true;
        fieldFlag = true;
        FLSCreatecheck = true; 
        userTheme = gen.getContextUserUiThemeDisplayed();
        mapObj = new Mapping__c();
        dupCheck = new list<Mapping__c>();
        dupChMap = new map<string, string>();
        populateObjects();
        selectedValue = objvalues[0].getValue();
        objLabel = objvalues[0].getLabel();
        doFLSCheck();
        dupCheck = [select Unique_Key__c from Mapping__c where Field_API_Name__c != ''];
        for(Mapping__c m:dupCheck){
            dupChMap.put(m.Unique_Key__c,m.Unique_Key__c);
            if(m.Unique_Key__c == 'Accountid')
                accId = m.Id;
            if(m.Unique_Key__c == 'Opportunityid')
                optyId = m.Id;
            //Ankur 11 Nov 2016 - Assign the Lead master record ID which can be used to tag the field mappings related to Lead
            if(m.Unique_Key__c == 'Leadid')
                leadId = m.Id;            
        }
        populateFields(); 
        objName = '';
        fieName = '';
    }
    //Method to fetch all the Objects
    public void populateObjects(){
        objvalues = new List<SelectOption>();        
        Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile('^\\w*?__\\B\\w*__');         
      //for(Schema.PickListentry picklistEntry:statusFieldDescription.getPicklistValues()){         
        for(Schema.SObjectType item : ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()) { 
            if(objvalues.size() == 12)
                break;
            Matcher filter = regEx.matcher(item.getDescribe().getLocalName().toLowerCase());
            if(!item.getDescribe().CustomSetting && (filter.find() == false)) 
            {   
                if(objName != null && objName != ''){
                    if(item.getDescribe().getLabel().toLowerCase().containsIgnoreCase(objName))
                        objvalues.add(new SelectOption(item.getDescribe().getLocalName(), item.getDescribe().getLabel()));                    
                    }
                else{                    
                    objvalues.add(new SelectOption(item.getDescribe().getLocalName(), item.getDescribe().getLabel()));

            }                   
          }        
        }       
        if(objvalues.size() == 0){
            dispFlag = false;
            selectedValue = '';
        }else{            
            dispFlag = true;           
            selectedValue = objvalues[0].getValue();          
        }
        populateFields();
      }
    //Method to fetch all the fields
    public void populateFields(){
        fieldLst = new list<mappingWrap>();
        fieldLstToShow = new list<mappingWrap>();
        system.debug('XXXXXX'+ fieName);
        counter = 0;
        schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        if(selectedValue != null && selectedValue != ''){
            if(selectedValue == 'Account' || selectedValue == 'Opportunity'){
                mapObj.Related_to_Object__c = selectedValue ;
            }
            else{
                  mapObj.Related_to_Object__c = null;
            }
            Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get(selectedValue);
            objLabel = ObjectSchema.getDescribe().getLabel();
            fieldMap = ObjectSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()){
                if(fieldLst.size() == 500)
                    break;
               if(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().isAccessible() && !dupChMap.containsKey(selectedValue+fieldName)){               
                    if(fieName != null && fieName != ''){
                        if(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel().toLowerCase().containsIgnoreCase(fieName))
                            fieldLst.add(new mappingWrap(fieldName, fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel(), string.valueOf(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType())));
                    }
                    else{
                        fieldLst.add(new mappingWrap(fieldName, fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel(), string.valueOf(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType())));
                    }
                }
            }
            totalSize = fieldLst.size();
            fieldLst.sort();
            if((counter+limitSize) <= totalSize){
                for(Integer i=0;i<limitSize;i++){
                    fieldLstToShow.add(fieldLst.get(i));
                }
            }else{
                for(Integer i=0;i<totalSize;i++){
                    fieldLstToShow.add(fieldLst.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        if(fieldLstToShow.size()== 0){
            fieldFlag = false;
        }else{
            fieldFlag = true;
        }

    }
    //Method to fetch related objects for mapObj.Related_to_Object__c
    public void populateRelatedObjects(){
        string seletcedObj = mapObj.Related_to_Object__c;
        if(seletcedObj == 'Master'){
            system.debug('@@' +seletcedObj);
            populateObjects();
        }
        else{
            objvalues = new List<SelectOption>();
            objvalues.add(new SelectOption(seletcedObj, seletcedObj));
            schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
            List<Schema.ChildRelationship> sc = schemaMap.get(seletcedObj).getDescribe().getChildRelationships();
            Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile('^\\w*?__\\B\\w*__'); 
            for(Schema.ChildRelationship item : sc) { 
                //if(objvalues.size() == 12)
                //    break;
                Matcher filter = regEx.matcher(item.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getLocalName().toLowerCase());
                if(!item.getChildSObject().getDescribe().CustomSetting && (filter.find() == false)) 
                {   
                    if(seletcedObj != null && seletcedObj != ''){
                        //if(!item.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getLabel().toLowerCase().containsIgnoreCase(seletcedObj))
                            objvalues.add(new SelectOption(item.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getLocalName(), item.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getLabel()));
                    }
                    else{
                        objvalues.add(new SelectOption(item.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getLocalName(), item.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getLabel()));
                    } 
                } 
            }
            if(objvalues.size() == 0){
                dispFlag = false;
                selectedValue = '';
            }else{
                dispFlag = true;
                selectedValue = seletcedObj;
            }
            populateFields();
            mapObj.Related_to_Object__c = selectedValue;
        }
    }

    //Method to save the selected records
    public Pagereference doSave(){
      if(!dupChMap.containsKey('Leadid')){
          Mapping__c mapObj = new Mapping__c();
          mapObj.Object_API_Name__c = 'Lead';
          mapObj.Object_Label__c = 'Lead';
          mapObj.Field_API_Name__c = 'id';
          mapObj.Field_Label__c = 'Lead ID';
          mapObj.Field_Type__c = 'ID';
          mapObj.Related_to_Object__c = 'Lead';
          mapObj.Enabled__c = true;
          mapObj.Unique_Key__c = 'Leadid';
          if(Schema.Sobjecttype.Mapping__c.isCreateable()){
              doFLSCheck();
              if(FLSCreatecheck)
                  Database.insert(mapObj);
          }
          leadId = mapObj.Id;
        }
        Mapping__c mappingobj = new Mapping__c();
        list<Mapping__c> maplst = new list<Mapping__c>();
        string errormsg = '';
        schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get(selectedValue);
        system.debug('sel val here' +ObjectSchema);
        for(mappingWrap w:fieldLst){            
            mappingobj = new Mapping__c();  
            system.debug('come inside for' +mappingobj);            
            if(w.isChecked){  
                system.debug('inside if' +w.isChecked);
                mappingobj.Object_Label__c = string.valueOf(ObjectSchema.getDescribe().getLabel());
                mappingobj.Object_API_Name__c = selectedValue;
                mappingobj.Field_API_Name__c = w.fName;
                mappingobj.Field_Label__c = w.fLabel;
                mappingobj.Field_Type__c = w.fType;
                mappingobj.Unique_Key__c = mappingobj.Object_API_Name__c + mappingobj.Field_API_Name__c;
                mappingobj.Enabled__c = true;
                mappingobj.Pick_values_from_SFDC__c = w.SFDC;
                if(mapObj.Related_to_Object__c == null){
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING,'Please select the related to object!'));
                    return null;
                }
                mappingobj.Related_to_Object__c = mapObj.Related_to_Object__c;
                if(mappingobj.Related_to_Object__c == 'Account'){
                    mappingobj.Mapping__c = accId;
                }
                else if(mappingobj.Related_to_Object__c == 'Opportunity' || mappingobj.Related_to_Object__c == 'Both'){
                    mappingobj.Mapping__c = optyId; 
                }
                //Ankur 11 Nov 2016 - Populate the Parent Object(Mapping__c) field with master Lead record ID
                else if(mappingobj.Related_to_Object__c == 'Lead')
                    mappingobj.Mapping__c = leadId;
                    maplst.add(mappingobj);

            }
        }
        if(maplst.size()==0){
            system.debug('IAMHERE!!');          
          //  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select a field!'));
            return null;
        }
        if(maplst != null && maplst.size()>0){
            doFLSCheck();
            if(Schema.Sobjecttype.Mapping__c.createable && FLSCreatecheck){
                insert maplst;
            }else{

            }
        }
        Pagereference pg;
        if(userTheme == 'Theme4d')
            pg = new Pagereference('/apex/JNMappingList_LEX');
        else
            pg = new Pagereference('/apex/JNMappingList');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
```

**wrapper:**

```
global class mappingWrap implements Comparable {
        global string fName{get;set;}
        global string fLabel{get;set;}
        global string fType{get;set;}
        global boolean isChecked{get;set;}
        global boolean SFDC{get;set;}
        global mappingWrap(string fN, string fL, string fT){
            fName = fN;
            fLabel = fL;
            isChecked = false;
            fType = fT;
            SFDC = true;
        }
         global Integer compareTo(Object ObjToCompare) {
            return fLabel.CompareTo(((mappingWrap)ObjToCompare).fLabel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code is incomplete to understand what your passing inside the "for loop" for  fieldLst.

Comment: I have only written one method for which that button is not working. FieldLst is a list of wrapper :     public list<mappingWrap> fieldLst{get;set;}  fieldLst=new list<mappingWrap>();

Comment: Where your passing value for fieldLst ?

Comment: That is in separate method. I am pasting the whole code for better understanding:

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,i was using html tag i.e. html tag="options" .I have removed this tag.We should not prefer to use html tags as salesforce has its own designed tags and attributes.